# What is this character? blank but it's code is 63(question mark)

Tags: xml, unicode, parsing-error

During xml pharsing, I met the error that is caused by some character.
I selected the character's code by this query script

```
SELECT UNICODE(' ') AS C1, UNICODE(' ') AS C2, UNICODE('?') AS C3
```

The character looks like blank but code is 63.(63 is question mark)
The character might be changed to normal blank character by paste to web control. So, look this link. [Code 63 Blank Character](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ld_BX8ph_R8tYFbAnkjcPk3Ji91ZebGa/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't understand your "script". It looks a bit like SQL. What input is it looking at, and how is this related to the XML that is giving you problems? Did you just copy/paste the offending character into the script? I would think that's very likely to distort the result. You need to look at the XML itself in a hex editor.

Comment: Also, please don't tell us you got an error without telling us what the error is. Chances are someone here understands the error message better than you do, and can tell you what it means.

Comment: Character 63 is the standard ASCII `?` character (Unicode codepoint [`U+003F QUESTION MARK`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/003f/index.htm)), which is what you get when the *original* character has been lost, typically because it passed through a charset conversion that does not support that character.  No space character has a character code of 63. That is just the *resulting* character after the original character has been *processed* in a manner that is not compatible with it.

Comment: So, you need to double-check that your XML input is actually encoded in the correct charset you are expecting, and that your XML logic is using that same charset when processing the input.